# jQuery inputs for picking a recurring date (RRULE spec RFC 5545)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rfc5545, rrule

There are a lot of javascript RRULE parsers, but is there any javascript or jQuery library that will help me show inputs that generate the RRULE conditions? Aka a "recurring date picker"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Took me 2 days to find it but here it is: https://github.com/superherogeek/rrule-generator-form